MQL5 WebRequest send json
input string WebhookURL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1288029176930242621/t-npSVLA5x8hv2QqAI8KfXbsiAXAtBMQcYyZyuuSYeFBOzr-AT-ldGGPAIXwUgeMOfB0";

void SendDiscordMessage(string message)
{
    Print("Raw message: ", message);
    
    // Escape newlines in the message
    StringReplace(message, "\n", "\\n");
    
    string json = "{\"content\":\"" + message + "\"}";
    Print("Final JSON Payload: ", json);
    
    char data[];
    StringToCharArray(json, data);
    ArrayResize(data, StringLen(json) + 1);  // Ensure the array has enough space

    char result[];
    string headers = "Content-Type: application/json";
    Print("Sending with headers: ", headers);
    string result_headers;

    int res = WebRequest("POST", WebhookURL, headers, 5000, data, result, result_headers);
    
    if (res < 0)
    {
        Print("Error sending message: ", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    string response = CharArrayToString(result);
    Print("HTTP Response Code: ", res);
    Print("Response Raw Output: ", response);
}

void OnStart()
{
    Print("Discord notification script running on MT5...");

    int totalPositions = PositionsTotal();
    Print("Total open positions: ", totalPositions);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalPositions; i++)
    {
        ulong ticket = PositionGetTicket(i);
        if (PositionSelectByTicket(ticket))
        {
            string symbol = PositionGetString(POSITION_SYMBOL);
            double entryPrice = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN);
            double stopLoss = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL);
            double takeProfit = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);

            // Format the message
            string message = StringFormat("New Trade: %s\\nEntry: %.2f\\nSL: %.2f\\nTP: %.2f",
                symbol, entryPrice, stopLoss, takeProfit);
                
            Print("Complete message: ", message);  // Log the complete message
            SendDiscordMessage(message);
        }
        else
        {
            Print("Failed to select position with ticket: ", ticket);
        }
    }
}


Output is:
2024.09.24 18:03:05.733 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  Discord notification script running on MT5...
2024.09.24 18:03:05.733 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  Total open positions: 1
2024.09.24 18:03:05.733 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  Complete message: New Trade: MYMZ24\nEntry: 42574.00\nSL: 0.00\nTP: 0.00
2024.09.24 18:03:05.733 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  Raw message: New Trade: MYMZ24\nEntry: 42574.00\nSL: 0.00\nTP: 0.00
2024.09.24 18:03:05.733 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  Final JSON Payload: {"content":"New Trade: MYMZ24\nEntry: 42574.00\nSL: 0.00\nTP: 0.00"}
2024.09.24 18:03:05.733 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  Sending with headers: Content-Type: application/json
2024.09.24 18:03:06.211 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  HTTP Response Code: 400
2024.09.24 18:03:06.211 TelegeramALert (MESZ24,H1)  Response Raw Output: {"message": "The request body contains invalid JSON.", "code": 50109}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you execute "StringToCharArray" for some reason is adding an extra character to the array which is recognized as an invalid character. So you just need to replace it. In my case I am replacing it with a blank space character and it is working.
StringToCharArray(json, data);
data[ArraySize(data) - 1] = ' ';

